# Distributing a mobileconfig file over the web

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, mobile-safari

I am dynamically generating (in a PHP script) a .mobileconfig file for iOS devices and then serve it over the web. I am delivering the file with the *application/x-apple-aspen-config* content type and with Content disposition as *attachment;filename=myprofile.mobileconfig*.

My problem is I keep getting an error that says: *Safari could not install a profile due to an unknown error*. What am I doing wrong? See the mobileconfig file below:

```
    $content =  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC \"-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN\" \"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd\">
<plist version=\"1.0\">
<dict>
    <key>PayloadContent</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>PayloadContent</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>DefaultsData</key>
                    <dict>
                        <key>apns</key>
                        <array>
                            <dict>
                                <key>apn</key>
                                <string>$apnName</string>
                                <key>password</key>
                                <string>$password</string>
                                <key>proxy</key>
                                <string></string>
                                <key>proxyPort</key>
                                <integer></integer>
                                <key>username</key>
                                <string>$userName</string>
                            </dict>
                        </array>
                    </dict>
                    <key>DefaultsDomainName</key>
                    <string>com.apple.managedCarrier</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>PayloadDescription</key>
            <string><removed before posting here></string>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string><removed before posting here></string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string><removed before posting here></string>
            <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
            <string><removed before posting here></string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.apn.managed</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>8B9A29CC-7C6E-4E32-B4AD-18ED3FDDB64D</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>PayloadDescription</key>
    <string><removed before posting here></string>
    <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
    <string><removed before posting here></string>
    <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
    <string><removed before posting here></string>
    <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
    <string><removed before posting here></string>
    <key>PayloadRemovalDisallowed</key>
    <false/>
    <key>PayloadType</key>
    <string>Configuration</string>
    <key>PayloadUUID</key>
    <string>975760AB-9CCE-4496-9D2F-04FD605DDBB9</string>
    <key>PayloadVersion</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>";
```

I am getting this issue both in the simulator and iPhone 3G and iPhone 4 devices.

Comment: hey @manuel can you help me in the PHP script that you wrote to generate this mobileconfig? I am an iPhone developer but have no knowledge of scripting langs and am stuck at creating mobileconfig progaramatically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16536494/downloading-mobileconfig-file-from-an-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that although proxy and proxyPort are optional, if proxyPort is included and is null, as in my xml then the profile won't install and will throw that annoying error. The solution is to remove it if it's not necessary.

Comment: Hi Manuel, Can you tell me to how to redirect back to our site and because i have to take device information