# Downloading "mobileconfig" file from an App

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, wifi

My org is creating an app, that will have certain wifi hotspots listed in a mobile config file, so that the user does not have to write the password for these wifi when he is in range.
I know this can be done using `.mobileconfig` file. But I have serious doubts.

Here are few questions regarding the app:

1. Can `.mobileconfig` file be created programatically. I cannot find a link to how to cretae this programatically (not using iPCU).
2. Will Apple allow an app that creates `.mobileconfig` file and asks the user to download it and install it, so as to change the wifi settings?
3. Is making the user download this `.mobileconfig` file only possible via Safari or Mail? Is there any way that this file be opened directly from the app to the settings screen?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: there are some similar questions on SO regarding the installation of a `.mobileconfig`. see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338035/installing-a-configuration-profile-on-iphone-programmatically

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1) Yes it can. It can be created as an XML file. In fact, you can open and edit an unsigned `.mobileconfig` file in a text editor and edit the fields. Keep in mind that if it's signed then any edits to the file will require you to re-sign it.

2) Apple will allow an app that downloads and installs a .mobileconfig via Safari, I've seen one on the App Store that does this.

3) Safari + Mail are the only ways to open them(on iOS).

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. some more info needed:
1. do u have any link to how to make this xml file? tags that are already defined/necessary etc.
2. can you tell me the app name :)

Comment: Well, since an unsigned .mobileconfig has the same structure as a .plist file, you should be able to create it programmatically the same way. See: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/CreatePropListProgram/CreatePropListProgram.html

Comment: Many VPN apps use the mobileconfig files. An example is the app Onavo which installs a proxy. See: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/onavo/id577491499?mt=8&ls=1

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this today? I've tried opening them on gmail but it just lets me preview the source code

Comment: Mail is not required as long as you can host the `.mobileconfig` on a public URL somewhere. You can just open that URL in Safari and it will work.

Comment: Airdrop is another option. Just send the xx.mobileconfig file from a mac / iPhone by AirDrop, then the receiving iPhone will advise the user to open Settings App to install the downloaded file.