# mobileconfig installation without using Safari

Tags: ios, vpn

Regarding iOS 8 profile install...

I'm trying to figure out how to design the simplest flow for VPN profile install while using Apple guidelines as entry point, but can't find any clue of clean VPN install implementation without using Safari.

My Q is: How to build the correct structure for a fast VPN profile install.

Pls find a cool reference: ZenMate iOS app. Can you assist?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently, the only way to install mobileconfig files are using Safari or Mail app on iOS.

To install the mobileconfig, you have some choices like:

1. Put the mobileconfig files on the web and open it by Safari
2. Send the mobileconfig by email and open it by Mail app
3. Package (or download) the mobileconfig files to your bundle and host a HTTP server by your app, then open the localhost link by safari through openURL: function.

**Or, the iOS 8 way, using the new framework Network Extension to establish the VPN connection.** And after trying the ZenMate iOS app, I believe it's what they use.

You can refer following resource for installing mobileconfig file:

[Downloading "mobileconfig" file from an App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16536494/downloading-mobileconfig-file-from-an-app)

[Installing a configuration profile on iPhone - programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338035/installing-a-configuration-profile-on-iphone-programmatically/)

Or this link for using Network Extension:

[Connect to VPN programmatically in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24970280/connect-to-vpn-programmatically-in-ios-8)

Comment: You can also send it via iMessage then save it to iCloud Drive and then open it in the Files app.

Comment: I sent the file to myself via email and saved it to My Files - from Files app I clicked the profile and then it appeared in the device Settings